# leftBarButtonItem position is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am attempting to add a custom button in the nav bar, however the placement in the nav bar is off to the left. Here is what I'm looking at (note the "Menu" button is too far left):

[image]

Here is how I'm adding the button to the current viewcontroller. setupMenu is called in ViewDidLoad.

```
 -(void)setupMenu{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {
    UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"GuidanceNavMenu", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popToOpenMenu)];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new;

    [menuButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIFont openSansFontOfSize:14.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                        [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                        nil]
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return menuButton;
}
```

Comment: As a test, what happens if you don't change the button's text attributes?

Comment: It results in exact same thing, only the text is default system style font.
![modified][url]
[url]:http://imgur.com/Xn8cTDT

Comment: http://imgur.com/Xn8cTDT

Comment: Are you sure the view controller is sized properly? Add something with an x origin of 0 and see if it is off the left edge of the screen or at the left edge of the screen.

Comment: It appears ok...here is a 50x50 UIView at 0, 0.
http://imgur.com/v6BFhUA

Comment: and same UIView offset 5,5
http://imgur.com/F1pdrKm

Comment: Then, try with UIEdgeInsets negative left , before that you have to add a button to uibarbuttonitem, and apply the negative UIEdgeInsets  to the button's contentEdgeInsets and add it to UIBarButtonItem, return the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Because, I tried the same code, with the different "setTitleTextAttributes" it works fine, So the problem might be with the font configuration.

Comment: I think, your `UINavigationController`'s view's frame is somewhat wrong. Do you change the view's frame of navigationController, or navigation bar's frame?

Comment: I had the same problem, and mine was caused by a category UINavigationItem-iOS7Spacing that reduces spacing of the UiBarButtonItem on navigation bar. In case you are using the same category developed by Marius Kažemėkaitis, you can adjust the spacer width in the spacer method. Personally, I just removed the category and add the spacer manually where I needed.